# Is it normal for a drain look like this?

Tags: bathroom

Drain looks like it has tree roots in it. What is the best way to get this cover off? And get rid of what appears to be tree roots in the drain?

Comment: If you'd care to [edit] your post to include a clear, focused picture or two of your situation I'm sure you'll get a reasonable answer. If not, well there's not much anyone can do to help you figure out how to get "this" drain cover off. As far as tree roots go, there are a variety of chemicals available at your local retailer that will kill tree roots. If those don't work, you'll need to call a plumber to snake your drain line.

Comment: Is it normal ? Many do have roots, roots in the drain will cause problems. A power snake with a root cutting head is used to cut roots. If roots are causing drainage problems expect this to increase with frequency as every spring when trees and bushes are growing once they get in they continue until it is every year depending on the type of roots.